# TCP in userspace vs kernel

Tags: networking, network-programming, kernel, scheduling

Is there a reliable study of the implications of implementing a reliable delivery transport protocol (TCP, or even QUIC) in userspace versus the traditional kernel-based approach ?

My intuition is that userspace scheduling is going to incur difficult to predict latency due to deferred ACK-ing and weaker scheduling guarantees. But how bad will it be ?

Comment: Why would you want to do it outside the kernel?

Comment: Because popularizing it is much much simpler this way. Also, maybe you don't have access to kernel source code or be allowed to modify it (for various reasons from security to performance reasons).